# & not working in BindingSource.Filter = string.Format

Tags: c#

when a projektname has a & in its name the filter does not work.
**A&O company**

is think i need to escape somehow?

```
projektBindingSource.Filter = string.Format("projektname like '*{0}*'", tb_filter.Text);
```

Comment: What is `projektBindingSource` ?

Comment: [As the docs explain](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.filter(v=vs.110).aspx), "The accepted filter syntax depends on the underlying data source". Obviously in your case, your data source treats the `&` character as special. It likely has a quoting mechanism you can use to specify a literal `&`, so you should pre-process the `tb_filter.Text` value to do what is required to do that before inserting it into the filter. You'll need to provide more context (at the very least, the data source) to get a more specific answer.

Comment: tb_filter is a simple textbox with trigger TbFilterTextChanged., which has the the filter line.
projektBindingSource comes from my Dataset connected to mysql server.

Answer (score 0):

Try following:

```cs
projektBindingSource.Filter = string.Format("projektname like '%{0}%'", tb_filter.Text);
```